# How to determine given GML version information?

Tags: gis, gml, gml-geographic-markup-lan

Given a GML, how to determine its version? For eg, i have below GML. Is there any way to determine if its version 1, 2 or higher?
I don't see any version information as such. So what is the accurate way to determine the same?

```
<gml:FeatureCollection
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengeospatial.net/gml http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/profiles/gmlJP2Profile/1.0.0/gmlJP2Profile.xsd">
  <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Null>withheld</gml:Null>
  </gml:boundedBy>
  <gml:featureMember>
    <gml:FeatureCollection>
      <gml:featureMember>
        <gml:RectifiedGridCoverage dimension="2" gml:id="RGC0001">
          <gml:rectifiedGridDomain>
            <gml:RectifiedGrid dimension="2">
              <gml:limits>
                <gml:GridEnvelope>
                  <gml:low>0 0</gml:low>
                  <gml:high>1023 1023</gml:high>
                </gml:GridEnvelope>
              </gml:limits>
              <gml:axisName>x</gml:axisName>
              <gml:axisName>y</gml:axisName>
              <gml:origin>
                <gml:Point gml:id="P0001" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">
                  <gml:pos>8.5001220703125 50.1249389648438</gml:pos>
                </gml:Point>
              </gml:origin>
              <gml:offsetVector srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">0.000244140625 0</gml:offsetVector>
              <gml:offsetVector srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">0 -0.0001220703125</gml:offsetVector>
            </gml:RectifiedGrid>
          </gml:rectifiedGridDomain>
          <gml:rangeSet>
            <gml:File>
              <gml:fileName>gmljp2://codestream/0</gml:fileName>
              <gml:fileStructure>Record Interleaved</gml:fileStructure>
            </gml:File>
          </gml:rangeSet>
        </gml:RectifiedGridCoverage>
      </gml:featureMember>
    </gml:FeatureCollection>
  </gml:featureMember>
</gml:FeatureCollection>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the schemas and their locations `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengeospatial.net/gml http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/profiles/gmlJP2Profile/1.0.0/gmlJP2Profile.xsd"`

They should all be versioned as can be seen at `http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/` and if not then you can check in a browser which shows `http://www.opengeospatial.net/gml` redirects to `http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd`

Comment: Is there no way to just look at the GML content and tell it's version? I mean without opening any additional URL but just looking at the GML content i shared in original question.

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. If it contained one of the new gml3 elements then maybe but it didn't